# How test callback click in child component that was passed from parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following parent component:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

export class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false,
    };
  }

  onClick = () => {
    // working
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Child handleClick={this.onClick} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

I need to check if callback fired in Child component, onClick method will be fired in Parent component.
I wrote such a test:

```
test("check callback fire", () => {
    let mockFn = jest.fn();
    Parent.prototype.onClick = mockFn;

    let wrapper = shallow(<Parent />);

    wrapper.find('Child').props().handleClick();

    expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

and I got an error

```
 Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.
```

How can I do that properly with jest and enzyme? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Your onClick function is on the object itself, not the prototype. You have to modify the object instance.

```
let mockFn = jest.fn();
let wrapper = shallow(<Parent />);
wrapper.find('Child').props().handleClick = mockFn; 
wrapper.find('Child').props().handleClick(); 
expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Having said that, you are calling onClick yourself, so it doesn't make sense to test that it was called.

You should test its effect, for example, part of the DOM is not showing.

You could also test that they component's state updates correctly, that is {show: false}

Comment: could you specify somehow? What should I do?

Comment: I could but then you would just test that a function you called was called, it doesn't make sense. It'd be better to test that the  state updated

Comment: I added setState just for example. In real that method do a lot of things

Comment: That's what you should test, that your component does everything it should when you click something. Testing that the function was called when you called it yourself just doesn't make sense.

Comment: A test that the function is called is simply testing that you hooked up the handler correctly, and for that you would render the actual DOM and trigger a click, making sure your function gets called. But that's also not useful since hooking up handlers is really done by React.

Answer (score 2):

the problem comes from the declaration of the `onClick` method, if you declare your function like this

```
onClick() {}
```

instead of

```
onClick = () => {}
```

your test should work because `onClick` will be present in the `Parent.prototype` object, note that `this` keyword in the `onClick` method will no longer refers to the class instance.

If you need to use arrow function (to get the correct value of `this`), you could modify your test :

```
test("check callback fire", () => {
  let mockFn = jest.fn();

  let wrapper = shallow(<Parent />);
  wrapper.instance().onClick = mockFn;

  wrapper.find('Child').props().handleClick();

  expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Using `onClick = () => {}` in the `Parent` class will not add the property to `Parent.prototype`, in fact it will declare an instance variable like this :

```
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onClick = () => {}
  }
}
```

By the way, the presence of `Fragment` inside your `render` method seems to be useless, you could remove it

```
render() {
  return <Child handleClick={this.onClick} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing this with two tests:

1. A unit test for the `Child` component that asserts its `onClick` prop is called when appropriate.
2. A unit test for the `Parent` that it properly sets the `onClick` prop of its `Child` when rendered.

With these two tests, you will be alerted if either of these pieces fails.