# Jest Test the callback

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I want to test the callback when a callback from the child component returns the parent component.
At parent SearchResult2 component is declared as follows to call the ResultTable child component:

SearchResult2.js

```
return (            
      <ResultTable
        handlerClick={result => this.callbackHandlerFunction(result)}
        searchResultData={listAddRessSearch}
        saveFilterSearchResultByRightTable={
          this.props.saveFilterSearchResultByRightTable
        }
      />
)
```

SearchResult2 contains child ResultTable.
I just want to test it to test the callback **handlerClick = {result => this.callbackHandlerFunction (result)}**

So I consulted on stackoverflow and tried writing UT code
Link: [How test callback click in child component that was passed from parent component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56067131/how-test-callback-click-in-child-component-that-was-passed-from-parent-component)

Here I use Jest to UT test.
UT code to test the above callback

SearchResult2.test.js

```
it('should invoke the callbackHandlerFunction callback', () => {
store.dispatch = jest.fn();
let wrapper = shallow(<SearchResult2 store={store} {...props} />);
let mockFn = jest.fn();
wrapper
  .dive()
  .dive()
  .instance().callbackHandlerFunction = mockFn;
wrapper
  .find('ResultTable')
  .props()
  .handlerClick();
expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);});
```

But the following error appears

[image: error]

Thanks you.

Comment: @skyboyer do you know the answer ? Please tell me

Comment: hard to say, there is no information what `this.callbackHandlerFunction` does. mocking internal method with `instance()....` is definitely bad move anyway.